# Angular select with async souce - default value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

I have lot of `<select>` bound to HTTP services (fetch data from underlying REST API). 
I am trying to respect Reactive pattern in Angular, this this is the code:

```html
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="bankAccountId" >
  <option *ngFor="let x of bankAccounts$ | async" [value]="x.id" >{{ x.name }}</option>
</select>
```

This result into blank select where user has to manually select option. I would like to pre-select first value in select (which is in most cases the value users would select manually). I know how to achieve this using imperative pattern.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.bankAccounts$ = this.httpService.getBankAccounts();

  this.bankAccounts$.subscribe(data => {
    this.form.patchValue({ bankAccountId: data[0].id });
  });
}
```

Is there any way how to achieve this without need to manually subscribe to Observable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator. so that we don't have to subscribe manually.

**Try this:**

```
this.bankAccounts$ = this.httpService.getBankAccounts().pipe(tap(data=> this.form.patchValue({ bankAccountId: data[0].id });));
```